# Jenkins mirror redirecting issue

Tags: jenkins, cicd

Is there any way to configure `jenkins` **not to redirect** to a mirror site based on location rather use the mirror site specified in the settings while downloading any plugins?

Answer (score 0):

Please check the topic of environment variables:
`JENKINS_UC_DOWNLOAD` and `JENKINS_UC`

You can set a variable and Jenkins should only use that one server to download plugins

```
JENKINS_UC_DOWNLOAD=http://example.url/jenkins/
```

Comment: I tried setting `JENKINS_UC_DOWNLOAD` but it failed while downloading the underlying dependent plugins from the default mirror server. Then I tried to set up `JENKINS_UC`  but it didn't work either.